# where login users are stored in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Where can the "login users" created be found in MySQL?  In SQL Server it is found under `Security-->Logins`.

I am creating new user as:

```
create user 'customer' @'localhost' identified by 'hassaan09';
grant all privileges on customer.* to 'customer' @'localhost' identified by 'hassaan09';
```

using MySQL Workbench 5.6

Comment: That is how you create a new database with a username, what you want to do is create a table within that database to serve as a users table where you will further store user login and password, etc.

Comment: while connecting vs2012 in connection string we need to provide username and password for that database. by above method i have created username and password for that database but i want to see where physically it exist in mysql workbench as in sql server i have mentioned it is founded under security-->logins

Answer (score 2):

As documented under [The MySQL Access Privilege System](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/privilege-system.html):

> Internally, the server stores privilege information in the grant tables of the `mysql` database (that is, in the database named `mysql`). The MySQL server reads the contents of these tables into memory when it starts and bases access-control decisions on the in-memory copies of the grant tables.

As documented under [Privilege System Grant Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/grant-table-structure.html):

> These `mysql` database tables contain grant information (emphasis added):
>
> - `user`: **Contains user accounts**, global privileges, and other non-privilege columns.

Therefore, they are stored in the `mysql.user` table:

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user
```